# Xamarin "namespace but is used like a type" error

Tags: c#, android

I was following a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZHLHrkvUt0&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=2) video that teaches us how to develop app with Xamarin Studio. I followed the exact thing that the guy did. But currently I'm getting the error

> "ListView is a 'namespace' but is used like a type"

Here's my code

```
int count = 1;
    private List<string> mItem;
    private ListView mListView;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        mListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.mylistview);
        mItem = new  List<string> ();
        //Add Items
        mItem.Add ("Tom");
        mItem.Add ("Bob");
        mItem.Add ("Jack");

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItem);

        mListView.Adapter = adapter;

    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a namespace... You didn't name you project "ListView"?

Comment: I named my project ListView

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I don't quite gget what you mean by " it shouldnt' be a namespace"

Comment: I think i found the solution, if i named my project different then "listview" it would work

Comment: Because you named your projekt ListView, the default namespace for it will also be ListView. That's why there is a namespace by that name, otherwise there isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you named your project ListView, whenever you use `ListView` in your code, it thinks youre referring to the namespace, because that is the name of your project. Then you cannot use ListView as a type anymore.

Pick a different project name and it should work. Keep in mind to never name projects after keywords or type names.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that, I will be aware of that. Thank you for your reminder